# gnome shell doesnt start after login

Tags: linux, gnome, gdm

i need to your help emergency .after crashed my system , restart it , after login its stuck in black screen .
i go to tty and get some logs , i know its related to limits policy  but when change it after reboot again changed again .
i dont know which part of system change it . plz help me.

```
Mar 23 03:53:21 kayvan-pc evolution-calen[3575]: creating thread 'Spawn-Subprocess-Backend': Error creating thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
Mar 23 03:53:21 kayvan-pc goa-daemon[3571]: creating thread 'gmain': Error creating thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
Mar 23 03:53:22 kayvan-pc gvfs-udisks2-vo[3541]: creating thread 'dconf worker': Error creating thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
Mar 23 03:53:23 kayvan-pc systemd-coredump[3633]: Process 3541 (gvfs-udisks2-vo) of user 1000 dumped core.
                                                  
                                                  Module linux-vdso.so.1 with build-id 6318c4a6aee96a4b3563df9857aef147f8c4bc48
                                                  Module libdconfsettings.so with build-id 7a4ba7af122c4d11168004a9ea6def330f02089f
                                                  Module libgvfscommon.so with build-id 643d4362b74f55b036829781680105545e0e1ad9
                                                  Module libgvfsdbus.so with build-id 80d171a1b9e2e4327b393f38166fc31d2925365d
                                                  Module libbrotlicommon.so.1 with build-id a4ba3f4b4571c8272343b621da812a6e24a202a7
                                                  Module libgraphite2.so.3 with build-id 47761dc11e553f519cde97ed9ee985be12ccdae2
                                                  Module libstdc++.so.6 with build-id 88ad4eff81a00c684abfe0f863e87434123d8943
                                                  Module libicudata.so.70 with build-id e1dcc2a88cfaafed882d09c90c668af0eed4efed
                                                  Module libdl.so.2 with build-id bb9bd2657bfba9f60bd34d2050cc63a7eb024bc4
                                                  Module libbrotlidec.so.1 with build-id 45defc036e918e0140a72f1fbce6e7692d38241d
                                                  Module libharfbuzz.so.0 with build-id ee57ebbf2c33ad97fd7ee7327cf63f419548e64e
                                                  Module libpng16.so.16 with build-id 2dc0bce07f199bf983c07a05fb95a6f4af83a9b3
                                                  Module libbz2.so.1.0 with build-id 919597c477c9b2cb9cdbb7745ed6494ac0e6da60
                                                  Module libexpat.so.1 with build-id a05c64fe82308a309e7653685c94ce71735f8a1a
                                                  Module libm.so.6 with build-id 596b63a006a4386dcab30912d2b54a7a61827b07
                                                  Module libicuuc.so.70 with build-id 2e245c2bf12f95fd8ab79b3a4be99524677cbd70
                                                  Module libtss2-sys.so.1 with build-id 1498ac4b48b90c1d3ac0f5f8f4d27d667bfc4771
                                                  Module libcrypto.so.1.1 with build-id 4c926b672d97886b123e03a008387aecf0786de4
                                                  Module libgpg-error.so.0 with build-id 82524ee3d1c4c2244d7cfdcc1e6eea5f9855f6c6
                                                  Module libpthread.so.0 with build-id 7fa8b52fae071a370ba4ca32bf9490a30aff31c4
                                                  Module librt.so.1 with build-id 4761858b348db8303e872e515aa8d56c046c921c
                                                  Module libblkid.so.1 with build-id 9e4bb910a2e63ba71cae0e3b89c07fdd45033ff2
                                                  Module libfreetype.so.6 with build-id 26c5f833068ff72660d1975cbc2074c3eb47fad8
                                                  Module libfontconfig.so.1 with build-id 9fdeb38479c4090d673efc2e8cb60176efe65da1
                                                  Module libxml2.so.2 with build-id 34aa03d6fadb52a051964f0e50a977efaea9482e
                                                  Module libtss2-tctildr.so.0 with build-id d45a42b5bc06ce0bc08516ee688eb690cd8c5c91
                                                  Module libtss2-rc.so.0 with build-id 683cdb1ae9b98aca4ccd4080b6f418bdd95d7b59
                                                  Module libtss2-mu.so.0 with build-id ddbc7a4374d0d9ccb2132b2d7497074920f6b65c
                                                  Module libtss2-esys.so.0 with build-id 964b48ed1a288f436f7b22b1d5d765765238bde4
                                                  Module ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with build-id c09c6f50f6bcec73c64a0b4be77eadb8f7202410
                                                  Module libgcc_s.so.1 with build-id 5d817452a709ca3a213341555ddcf446ecee37fa
                                                  Module libgcrypt.so.20 with build-id db45f5d5e0f7af1e77324fea1885f974619ad268
                                                  Module libcap.so.2 with build-id eb6dae97527fc89dbb0d5bb581a15acd02ae9f56
                                                  Module liblz4.so.1 with build-id e63600ab23b2f6997f42fac2fa56e1f02ce159a1
                                                  Module libzstd.so.1 with build-id 72f3511cba7db578f6a2647925f35664da6c838b
                                                  Module liblzma.so.5 with build-id 8b615460aa230708c5183f16bede67aa0437d95e
                                                  Module libudev.so.1 with build-id 7dc938362569112855b6086de066cd6a18d1b978
                                                  Module libpcre.so.1 with build-id 845483dd0acba86de9f0313102bebbaf3ce52767
                                                  Module libffi.so.8 with build-id f90d8b734f6de9b25faedb8cbfab7054dafc0a42
                                                  Module libmount.so.1 with build-id 765508fe9812e693ac41fd3d0aedd65d7a78b287
                                                  Module libz.so.1 with build-id 0c1459c56513efd5d53eb3868290e9afee6a6a26
                                                  Module libgmodule-2.0.so.0 with build-id 0f0921c3ff98f0afe7fafbb123581acec5f7de29
                                                  Module libc.so.6 with build-id 85766e9d8458b16e9c7ce6e07c712c02b8471dbc
                                                  Module libbluray.so.2 with build-id 3ed75b9f8aa64ee4707bbfcb986bcf289432d673
                                                  Module libsecret-1.so.0 with build-id 56982ddb5f2ffaaef5c89862f2037331b70d40e0
                                                  Module libsystemd.so.0 with build-id 05d0460efefd339d315812f9506aecc5a5d22200
                                                  Module libudisks2.so.0 with build-id 48a6b15347d90602f91b39909dcf73379550e74e
                                                  Module libgudev-1.0.so.0 with build-id a9f734ea9206d637d5aacfbd86298c91cdc1a33a
                                                  Module libglib-2.0.so.0 with build-id 0fcc81d3dfd68bddbf63423156549fc66939e8ca
                                                  Module libgobject-2.0.so.0 with build-id 1ab19051c262a2c995e86ea2b0af7e8ab70798f3
                                                  Module libgio-2.0.so.0 with build-id 8418b6a6a164774cde5db9d63d03911bb9823368
                                                  Module gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor with build-id ce05e018345dcbb595fd42ab39f97191c7996e79
                                                  Stack trace of thread 3541:
                                                  #0  0x00007fe0e6456290 g_log_structured_array (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x5c290)
                                                  #1  0x00007fe0e645655a g_log_default_handler (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x5c55a)
                                                  #2  0x00007fe0e6457a0d g_logv (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x5da0d)
                                                  #3  0x00007fe0e6457d14 g_log (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x5dd14)
                                                  #4  0x00007fe0e647ffcc g_thread_new (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x85fcc)
                                                  #5  0x00007fe0e6764fcc n/a (libdconfsettings.so + 0x5fcc)
                                                  #6  0x00007fe0e6766ed9 n/a (libdconfsettings.so + 0x7ed9)
                                                  #7  0x00007fe0e6767104 n/a (libdconfsettings.so + 0x8104)
                                                  #8  0x00007fe0e6558c4f n/a (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x21c4f)
                                                  #9  0x00007fe0e655a0c3 g_object_new_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x230c3)
                                                  #10 0x00007fe0e655a62e g_object_new (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x2362e)
                                                  #11 0x0000558439c4cd5d n/a (gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor + 0x16d5d)
                                                  #12 0x00007fe0e657171a g_type_create_instance (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x3a71a)
                                                  #13 0x00007fe0e6558939 n/a (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x21939)
                                                  #14 0x0000558439c491aa n/a (gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor + 0x131aa)
                                                  #15 0x00007fe0e6558d95 n/a (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x21d95)
                                                  #16 0x00007fe0e6559af5 g_object_new_with_properties (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x22af5)
                                                  #17 0x00007fe0e655a65a g_object_new (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x2365a)
                                                  #18 0x0000558439c54e42 n/a (gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor + 0x1ee42)
                                                  #19 0x0000558439c420f0 n/a (gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor + 0xc0f0)
                                                  #20 0x00007fe0e5fb4310 __libc_start_call_main (libc.so.6 + 0x2d310)
                                                  #21 0x00007fe0e5fb43c1 __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.34 (libc.so.6 + 0x2d3c1)
                                                  #22 0x0000558439c42195 n/a (gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor + 0xc195)
                                                  
                                                  Stack trace of thread 3543:
                                                  #0  0x00007fe0e608d2af __poll (libc.so.6 + 0x1062af)
                                                  #1  0x00007fe0e64a5086 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xab086)
                                                  #2  0x00007fe0e644e433 g_main_loop_run (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x54433)
                                                  #3  0x00007fe0e669a14c n/a (libgio-2.0.so.0 + 0x10814c)
                                                  #4  0x00007fe0e647e815 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x84815)
                                                  #5  0x00007fe0e60145c2 start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x8d5c2)
                                                  #6  0x00007fe0e6099584 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x112584)
                                                  
                                                  Stack trace of thread 3542:
                                                  #0  0x00007fe0e608d2af __poll (libc.so.6 + 0x1062af)
                                                  #1  0x00007fe0e64a5086 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xab086)
                                                  #2  0x00007fe0e644c455 g_main_context_iteration (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x52455)
                                                  #3  0x00007fe0e644c4a2 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x524a2)
                                                  #4  0x00007fe0e647e815 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x84815)
                                                  #5  0x00007fe0e60145c2 start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x8d5c2)
                                                  #6  0x00007fe0e6099584 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x112584)
                                                  ELF object binary architecture: AMD x86-64
░░ Subject: Process 3541 (gvfs-udisks2-vo) dumped core
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
░░ Documentation: man:core(5)
░░ 
░░ Process 3541 (gvfs-udisks2-vo) crashed and dumped core.
░░ 
░░ This usually indicates a programming error in the crashing program and
░░ should be reported to its vendor as a bug.
Mar 23 03:53:23 kayvan-pc systemd[3336]: Failed to start Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit UNIT has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 241 and the job result is failed.
Mar 23 03:53:23 kayvan-pc systemd-coredump[3613]: Process 3571 (goa-daemon) of user 1000 dumped core.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the log file, i think its a problem related to kernel of the distro, u can try reinstalling the kernel by going into the advance option by using flased usb stick.

Or

In tty -

```
sudo mhwd-kernel [-i] [new kernel: linux(version)] [optional - remove the current kernel: rmc]
```

install the lates kernel. You can google for the latest version.

Or

You might have to reinstall the entire distro.

In manjaro theres a option to change the kernel u can try that
`mhwd-kernel -li`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).